# Java: How do I achieve a pointer effect without method calls?

Tags: java

I am trying to make some sort of integer (be it `int` or `Integer`), `x`, that equals the sum of two other integers: `a` and `b`. `a` and `b` will change on occasion, so I want `x` to always be up-to-date.

Is there a way to do this without calling a `getX()`-like method that returns `a` + `b`?

Comment: What do you have against method calls?

Comment: If your really hard pressed to keep to this path, then you can use a combination of [Observable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html)/[Observer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) to accomplish this. Wrap up your operands in an observable, and your result in an observer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, yes, but it's no better than having a getter: the obvious alternative is to have setter methods for `a` and `b` that update `x`.

But I suspect that's not what you wanted.

There's no way to 'link' ints or Integers in Java without some kind of method call to update them.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to do that.